# Get NuGet package version from remote repository specified by URL without using NuGet.Core

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-4.6.1

NuGet.Core has been deprecated, I am struggling to find out an API to get NuGet package version from remote repository specified by URL. Using IPackageRepository was quite straight forward but I am not getting any way how to do it without using NuGet.Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: FactoryExtensionsV3.GetCoreV3 probably refers to "NuGet version 3", not NuGet's v3 HTTP API. So, this code works for local file feeds as well as both V2 and V3 HTTP feeds. Just change the URL passed to PackageSource.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var packageSource = new PackageSource("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
    var sourceRepository = new SourceRepository(packageSource, FactoryExtensionsV3.GetCoreV3(null));

    var metadata = await sourceRepository.GetResourceAsync<MetadataResource>();
    var cacheContext = new SourceCacheContext();
    var versions = await metadata.GetVersions("newtonsoft.json", cacheContext, NullLogger.Instance, CancellationToken.None);

    foreach (var version in versions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found version " + version.ToNormalizedString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for me. Further I found it works for V2 http with this change:     
var sourceRepository = FactoryExtensionsV3.GetCoreV2(Repository.Factory, packageSource);

Comment: FYI, [both `GetCoreV2` and `GetCoreV3` call into the same method](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol/FactoryExtensionsV3.cs), which [adds all providers](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/840b09a4cecda6ae8fd1c07967874fe8061ece63/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol/Repository.cs#L42-L92). So, it's unnecessary to call different methods for file feeds or v2 vs v3 http feeds. The same code works, just change the source URL.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a package to make it easier to interact with NuGet V3 servers: https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet/tree/master/src/BaGet.Protocol#list-package-versions

```cs
NuGetClient client = new NuGetClient("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");

IReadOnlyList<NuGetVersion>> versions = await client.ListPackageVersionsAsync("Newtonsoft.Json");

foreach (NuGetVersion version in versions)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Found version: {version}");
}
```

Please let me know if you have any feedback or suggestions! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will look into it! :)